# Review queues on iOS allow selecting inactive option 'Pending edit'

Tags: bug, review, ios

Normally, in the First/Late Questions/Answers review queues, when there is a pending edit to the post, the 'Edit' option is replaced with 'Pending edit' which can't be selected:

[image]

However, in Safari on iOS, it is possible to select 'Pending edit' from the dropdown:

[image]

and the Submit button stays active (but doesn't do anything when you hit it). This can be rather confusing - perhaps Pending Edit should be removed from the dropdown, IIRC it's not possible to disable it. Or the button should be made inactive after selecting 'Pending edit'.

Comment: Perhaps related: [I am able to select the option "Pending edit" to complete a review on mobile, but then clicking on "Submit" does nothing](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4478) on [anime.meta.se].

Comment: @TheAmplitwist yes, definitely the same bug. Thanks for finding/remembering that!

Comment: Out of curiosity what happens if you try and submit it with the pending edit opption?

Comment: @Ethan *but doesn't do anything when you hit it*